# Saving State of MainActivity when opening Settings/About

Tags: android, android-activity, save, state, restore

I have some `SeekBars`, a `Switch` and `CheckBox` on my `MainActivity` when I open the settings from the menu with:

```
Intent settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(settings);
return true;
```

Now when I go back (ActionBar or Back button) is lose the progress of the `SeekBars` and the state of the switch and `checkbox`.

`onSaveInstanceState` seems to save it, but `onRestoreInstanceState` never gets called so it restores nothing.

I dont want to save the values permanently, just when opening Settings or About.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onRestoreInstanceState` is only called after the OS kills your application (orientation change or memory free-up action. It your just going to the settings dialog and returning to the application, it should still be running in the background, and the states should all stay the same.

Comment: Hmm Im probably doing something wrong then. When I go back from Settings/About `onCreate` from MainActivity gets called and everything is getting reset to 0.

Comment: Setting the `launchMode` of the `MainActivity` to `singleTop` worked.